# Import problems with Python namespace packages

Tags: python, import, namespace-package

I am trying to use Python [namespace packages concept](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/) to split my library across multiple directories. In general, it works, but I have a problem regarding importing names to projects package level.

My project structure is following:

[image: Example project structure]

> **`project1/coollibrary/__init__.py`**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)

from .foomodule import foo
```

> **`project1/coollibrary/foomodule.py`**

```py
def foo():
    print ('foo')
```

> **`project2/coollibrary/__init__.py`**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)

from .barmodule import bar
```

> **`project2/coollibrary/barmodule.py`**

```py
def bar():
    print ('bar')
```

Both projects are in the PATH:

```
$ echo ${PYTHONPATH}
/home/timo/Desktop/example/project1:/home/timo/Desktop/example/project2
```

And I am running code from here:

```
$ pwd
/home/timo/Desktop/example
```

```py
$ python3
>>> import coollibrary
>>> coollibrary.foo() # works
foo
>>> coollibrary.bar() # does not work (the problem)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
>>> import coollibrary.barmodule 
>>> coollibrary.barmodule.bar() # works
bar
```

How to fix the code so that I could import both `foo` and `bar` directly from `coollibrary` package. Also, is there a solution that works for both Python2.7 and Python3.4 (other versions not required).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Python 3.3, you can use [PEP 420 -- Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Basically, you would remove your `__init__.py` file in both repositories, and add:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=['coollibrary.{foomodule/barmodule}'],
    namespace_packages=['coollibrary'],
    ...
)
```

to your `setup.py`.

Can't help you with Python 2.7 though...

Comment: I understand (I think) how implicit namespace packages work once they are installed, but how do I leverage them during local development?